# NullPointerException en JPA al hacer una busqueda por parámetros en MySQL (Eclipse)

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, parametros, nullpointerexception

Qué tal comunidad! Me podrían ayudar a resolver este problema de favor?

Soy nuevo en la programación; estoy practicando con JPA utilizando Hibernate como proveedor y MySQL para la DB.
En mi proyecto de práctica utlizo una clase como View, una clase JpaUtils en donde creo la instancia del EntityManager, un Controller, un DAO y un DAO Genérico (en donde tengo la lógica principal de los métodos más empleados como ".persist()", ".merge()", etc.)

En esta parte del proyecto deseo crear un método para buscar en la DB usando dos parámetros (que son dos atributos de mi Clase Duenio): el 'nombreDuenio' y el 'telefono'.

Estoy usando el método ".createQuery()" del EntityManager para hacer la consulta y en mi DB sólo tengo un registro (mismo que estoy intentando obtener para probar el método); el problema es que siempre obtengo un NPE justo en la línea que tengo el método ".createQuery()".

Por lo que entiendo, el resultado de ese método es "null" pero el registro sí existe (copio y pego los datos guardados de las columnas en el codigo y aun así no obtengo ese registro); adjunto el código de las Clases

```
// Fragmento del método del View (usando java.swing)
  // CONSTRUCTOR:
    public RegistrarDatosView() {
        Container container = getContentPane();
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        configurarCamposVentanaRegistro(container);
        configurarAccionesBotones();
        
        setTitle("Peluqueria Canina - Nuevo Registro -");
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        this.mascotaController = new MascotaController();
        this.duenioController = new DuenioController();     
    }

private void buscarDuenio(){
        if(txtNombreDuenio.getText().isBlank() || txtTelefono.getText().isBlank()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Se necesitan el Nombre completo y Teléfono del Dueño");
            return;
        }
        String nombreDuenio = txtNombreDuenio.getText();
        String telDuenio = txtTelefono.getText();
        var duenioBuscado = duenioController.buscarDuenioPorNombreYTelefono(nombreDuenio, telDuenio);
        if(duenioBuscado != null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "¡Registro Encontrado!");

            txtTelefono.setText(duenioBuscado.getTelefono());
            txtDireccion.setText(duenioBuscado.getDireccion());
            txtIdDuenio.setText(duenioBuscado.getIdDuenio().toString()); 
            
        }else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No existe un registro con esos datos");
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Clase JpaUtils
public class JpaUtils {
    private static EntityManagerFactory eMF = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PCJpa");
    
    public static EntityManager getEntityMan(){
        return eMF.createEntityManager();       
    }
}
```

```
// Fragmento de la Clase controller con el método en cuestión
public class DuenioController {
   // ATRIBUTO:
    private DuenioDao duenioDao;
    
    public DuenioController() {
        this.duenioDao = new DuenioDao(new JpaUtils().getEntityMan(), Duenio.class);
    }

    public Duenio buscarDuenioPorNombreYTelefono(String nombreDuenio, String telefono) {
        return duenioDao.buscarPorNombreYTelefono(nombreDuenio, telefono);  
    }
}
```

```
     //Fragmento de la clase DAO con el método en cuestión
public class DuenioDao extends GenericDao<Duenio> {
    
//  ATRIBUTOS
    protected EntityManager em;
    protected Class<Duenio> clase;

 // CONSTRUCTORES       
    public DuenioDao(EntityManager em, Class<Duenio> clase) {
        super(em, clase);       
    }
    public Duenio buscarPorNombreYTelefono(String nombreDuenio, String telefono) {

        String jpql = "SELECT d FROM Duenio d WHERE d.nombreDuenio=:nombreDuenio AND d.telefono=:telefono";
        try{
            super.conectar();
            TypedQuery<Duenio> query=  em.createQuery(jpql, Duenio.class)
                                         .setParameter("nombreDuenio", nombreDuenio)
                                         .setParameter("telefono", telefono);
            return query.getSingleResult();
        
        }catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Ocurrió un error al buscar la Entidad", e);
        }finally {
            super.desconectar();
        }
    }
}
```

```
//Fragmento de clase GenericDao
public class GenericDao<T> {
    
    protected EntityManager em;
    protected Class<T> clase;

    public GenericDao(EntityManager em, Class<T> clase) {
        this.em = em;
        this.clase = clase;
    }
    
    public void conectar() {
        if(!em.isOpen()) em = new JpaUtils().getEntityMan();
    }
    
    public void desconectar() {
        if(em.isOpen()) em.close();
    }
}
```

```
// Clase Duenio
@Entity
@Table(name="tbduenios")
public class Duenio {
 // ATRIBUTOS
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idDuenio;
    
    @Column(length = 60)
    private String nombreDuenio;
    
    @Column(length = 10, unique = true)
    private String telefono;
    
    @Column(length = 300)
    private String direccion;
    
    private Boolean activo;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "duenio", 
               cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE},
               fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Mascota> mascota;
 
// CONSTRUCTORES
    public Duenio() {   
    }
    public Duenio(Integer idDuenio, String nombreDuenio, String telefono) {
        this.idDuenio = idDuenio;
        this.nombreDuenio = nombreDuenio;
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }
    public Duenio(String nombreDuenio, String telefono, String direccion) {
        this.nombreDuenio = nombreDuenio;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.activo = true;
    }
    public Duenio(Integer idDuenio, String nombreDuenio, String telefono, String direccion) {
        this(nombreDuenio, telefono, direccion);
        this.idDuenio = idDuenio;       
        this.activo = true;
    }

 // MÉTODOS 
    public Integer getIdDuenio() {
        return idDuenio;
    }
    public void setIdDuenio(Integer idDuenio) {
        this.idDuenio = idDuenio;
    }
    public String getNombreDuenio() {
        return nombreDuenio;
    }
    public void setNombreDuenio(String nombreDuenio) {
        this.nombreDuenio = nombreDuenio;
    }
    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }
    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }
    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }
    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }
    public Boolean getActivo() {
        return activo;
    }
    public void setActivo(Boolean activo) {
        this.activo = activo;
    }
    public List<Mascota> getMascota() {
        return mascota;
    }
    public void setMascota(List<Mascota> mascota) {
        this.mascota = mascota;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Duenio [idDuenio=" + idDuenio + ", nombreDuenio=" + nombreDuenio + ", apellidoPaternoDuenio="
                + ", telefono=" + telefono + ", direccion=" + direccion + "]";
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(activo, direccion, idDuenio, mascota, nombreDuenio, telefono);
    }   
}
```

Espero el error no sea algo muy newbie jajajaja, pero la verdad no sé qué hacer; muchas gracias por el apoyo, comunidad! :D

Comment: Buenas, Oscar, bienvenido al sitio. Creo que te está dando NullPointerException porque nunca asignas el atributo em en tu clase DuenioDao. Inicializas el de su clase padre en el constructor. Elimina ese atributo en el dao hijo y crea un método get en el padre que sirva para accederlo en el hijo y que llames antes del createQuery: getEntityManager().createQuery(...)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: Muchas gracias,@RubioRic! El error sí era un tema del atributo y la inicialización del EntityManager al usar la herencia de la Super Clase; sí era un error de newbie jajajaja  pero me sirvió para reformar mi entendimiento en este tema.

De nuevo, muchas gracias!